# Docker container on Marathon doesn't finish

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I have Mesos cluster consists of 3 CentOS6.5 machines.

ZooKeeper and Mesos-Master is running on one of the machines and Mesos-Slave is running on each machine.

Also, Marathon is running on master node.

Then, I am trying to run docker containers on Marathon, following [this instruction](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2014/09/25/marathon-0-7-0-released/) by Mesosphere.

`job.json` is like as follows,

```
{
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "libmesos/ubuntu"
    }
  },
  "id": "ubuntu",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.5,
  "mem": 512,
  "uris": [],
  "cmd": "date -u +%T"
}
```

Then I run following command,

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" <master-hostname>:8080/v2/apps -d@job.json
```

Then on Marathon Web UI, I can see the Docker container is "Deploying" status even after long time.

And on Mesos-Master Web UI, I can see the Task is in "STAGING" status after long time.

On Sandbox pane, I can see the stdout and the command seems to completed successfly. No problem.

stderr is like this,

```
I0416 19:19:49.254998 29178 exec.cpp:132] Version: 0.22.0
I0416 19:19:49.257824 29193 exec.cpp:206] Executor registered on slave 20150416-160950-109643786-5050-30728-S0
```

stdout is like this,

```
Registered executor on master-hostname
10:19:49
```

**But I expect the container(TASK) to finish after completed the command.**
**Is it possible?**
**If possible, how to do that way?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task will finish (you should be able to see in the Mesos completed tasks) but the container will be restarted by Marathon. Marathon is for long-running apps.

If you don't want your application to be running continuously, you should take a look at another framework like Chronos.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Then, what I have to do is configuring a framework on Chronos to run just once.

Answer (score 0):

Marathon is for long running processes. Even if you remove the containers, marathon will try to restart these. One more thing that I observed is that Marathon tries to launch containers and continue to do that till you are left with no memory and CPU. When you are out of resources your task will go in stage state.